# AWS CloudFormation stack fails create due to resource already exists in stack that has been deleted

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless

When creating a new CloudFormation stack, CREATE fails with the following error:

```
[RESOURCE] already exists in stack [DELETE_COMPLETE status stack ARN]
```

I have already verified the resource is no longer in the AWS account.

Comment: Could you please include a snippet of your CloudFormation template where the failing [RESOURCE] is mentioned? This error happens when you explicitly declare multiple resources with the same name.

Comment: Which resource type and region? May be an intermittent service issue

Comment: As of yesterday I am seeing the same issue in us-east-1 with some Lambda functions that were created and deleted 5 or so days ago. I don't really have the time to investigate further.

Comment: @josesigna did you get the solution to this? I am getting the same error in eu-central-1 region. While the existing stack is already deleted.

Answer (score 1):

It's happening with me too (us-east-1), since yesterday (2020-09-30).
I tried to redeploy (the same stack) several times WITHOUT SUCCESS.

I also tried:

- list the stack arn on awscli to try to delete manually
- list the old resource arn, to try to force deleting the old stack on awscli ... all WITHOUT SUCCESS

It seems to be an AWS bug, **I would suggest you opening a ticket on AWS support to try to solve it** (I'm doing it)

**One alternative is to create a new stack changing the resource name** (here we usually use a suffix on the resource, based on stackname variable to have multiples deploys stacks)

Comment: For about a week now we are no longer seeing this problem, under the same conditions.